# How to call Fragment from Fragment along with data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-listfragment

Earlier I was calling Activity from Fragment along with data, using below code:

**ListCategoryFragment.java :**

```
          case categoryFirst:
             Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), ListItemActivity.class);
             intent1.putExtra("category", "Category - 1");
             startActivity(intent1);    
           break;
```

**ListItemActivity.java :**

```
    Bundle bdl = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    KEY_CATEGORY = bdl.getString("category");
```

But now i am Calling Fragment from Fragment, using below code:

**ListCategoryFragment.java :**

```
private static final int categoryFirst = 0;

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

    // Set up different intents based on the item clicked: 
    switch (position)
    {

           case categoryFirst:
                ListItemFragment fragment1 = new ListItemFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("category", "Category - 1");
                fragment1.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
               fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
             break;

           default:
             break;
    }
```

**ListItemFragment.java :**

```
        Bundle bdl = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        KEY_CATEGORY = bdl.getString("category");  // Line No. - 67
```

**Log Says:**

```
10-22 02:06:06.930: W/dalvikvm(914): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.androidbegin.absviewpagertutorial.ListItemFragment.onCreateView(ListItemFragment.java:67)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-22 02:06:06.959: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 02:06:09.900: I/Process(914): Sending signal. PID: 914 SIG: 9
```

Comment: FragmentTransaction add (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)
fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: why is this case "categoryFirst" ? Can't we directly call ?

Comment: Log and see if you pass inside your listener, and check that the invocation of the second fragment is actually ran through.

Comment: You shouldn't be communicating from one Fragment to another. The design philosophy of Fragments is they should be completely self-contained and one Fragment should never rely on any other Fragment existing. All communication should be via callbacks implemented by the Activity which creates the Fragments and only that Activity should know what Fragments exist at any time and should be responsible for passing data between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are looking for sending data via bundle from one fragment to other.

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Bundle has put methods for lots of data types.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Then in your Fragment, retrieve the data (e.g. in onCreate()) with:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
```

Comment: but to call another Fragment along with passing data

Comment: calling procedure will be the same, as you are calling without data.

Comment: Actually not getting what i need to write here:transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);  in place of fragment_container

Comment: yeah sure, I am showing Category List using Fragments (given Categories in Static way) then i want to show List of Items using LocalHost to fetch data from json using Fragment, I hope you got my point

Comment: This is the correct answer. The getArguements() and setArguements() functions are members of the fragment class meamt to solve this problem. The Bundle class was provided  by the android team for this purpose. I see signs that the android team prefers the newer fragment style over the strict cardstack model, and as handset displays trend larger, I expect Google to deprecate many of the older techniques. If you want to go with the grain and work with  the framework and the Android team, it is probably better to change your coding style to the fragment model sooner rather than later!

Answer (score 0):

To get the data sent to the ListItemFragment:

```
String s = getArguments().getString("category");
```

To create a ListItemFragment correctly:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1).commit();
```

Should work correctly. I haven't tested with this specifically. Your code didn't switch fragments because you never called replace().